# Does "AND title <> 'MySQL'" in the query in question use full text indexing?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, where-clause, full-text-indexing

I am working on a query and want to make it more efficient if possible.

Table is like:

```
CREATE TABLE articles (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(200),
    FULLTEXT (title)
) Engine=MyISAM;
```

Query that need to be efficient:

```
SELECT * FROM articles 
WHERE 
MATCH (title)
  AGAINST ('+MySQL' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND title <> 'MySQL';
```

I have 2 questions regarding above query:

1. Do `AND title <> 'MySQL'` used full text index?
2. Can we make it more efficient?

You can find the fiddle here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/268411/2/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do `AND title <> 'MySQL'` used full text index?

No.

The first term, `MATCH...AGAINST` will use a fulltext index, and select only rows where the word occurs in the title. That will cause the query to examine only matching rows.

Then, examining those rows, the second term will further filter for rows where the title is more than just the single word 'MySQL'. The titles will still *contain* 'MySQL' but they must have other words too (or at least some other characters).

> Can we make it more efficient?

Not with MySQL.

I believe the optimizer will either choose to use the fulltext index for the `MATCH...AGAINST` search, or it will use a B-tree index for another type of predicate, but not both.

If you want it to be more efficient, you'd have to index the data with some other search engine, e.g. ElasticSearch or Sphinx Search.

Comment: Thank you @Bill Karwin for your time, should we ignore overload of  `AND title <> 'MySQL'` if we have 500000 rows in our table?

Comment: The second term will only be evaluated for rows that match the first term. I assume this will be a small subset of the 500k rows.